# Incorporate legacy (non-requirable) js libs into a browserify bundle?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browserify

How does one incorporate legacy (non-requirable) js libs into a browserify bundle?

Basically they should be prepended in some order to the the bundle.js but I can't find an example of it anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Make them requireable?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix No.

Comment: @boom take a look at https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim